# JavaFX ProgressBar/ProgressIndicator: listen for change from multiple Sliders

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding, progress-bar

**Situation**: Have multiple sliders | want progress bar to change with each slider move. Right now only one slider will move the progress bar but the text field shows all the data.

Is there a better way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
@FXML
ProgressIndicator pb;

@FXML
Slider slider1, slider2, slider3, slider4, slider5, slider6, slider7, slider8;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

  field.textProperty().bind(Bindings.concat(
            slider1.valueProperty()
            .add(slider2.valueProperty()
            .add(slider3.valueProperty()
            .add(slider4.valueProperty()
            .add(slider5.valueProperty()
            .add(slider6.valueProperty()
            .add(slider7.valueProperty()
            .add(slider8.valueProperty())))))))));

       slider1.valueProperty().addListener(
            (ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number old_val,
             Number new_val) -> {
                    //sets the Progress bar to new value
                pb.setProgress(new_val.doubleValue());


            });
            }

        }
```

[slider example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aypno.png)

Comment: Why do you need multiple slider to control only one ProgressBar ?

Comment: For example: If I had 4 sliders I want each slider to represent 25% of the progress bar. All four sliders combined would represent 100% when they are all at the max. I specifically want to use that format for a visual gage I am working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply bind the `progressProperty` of the `ProgressIndicator` to the `valueProperty` of the `Slider`s while keeping in mind that the `progressProperty` of the indicator has the boundaries of 0 to 1:

> A positive value between 0 and 1 indicates the percentage of progress
>   where 0 is 0% and 1 is 100%.

**An example:**

```
Slider slider1 = new Slider(0d, 1d, 0d);
Slider slider2 = new Slider(0d, 1d, 0d);
Slider slider3 = new Slider(0d, 1d, 0d);
Slider slider4 = new Slider(0d, 1d, 0d);

ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator();

pi.progressProperty().bind(slider1.valueProperty().divide(4d).add(slider2.valueProperty().divide(4d))
        .add(slider3.valueProperty().divide(4d)).add(slider4.valueProperty().divide(4d)));

VBox vbox = new VBox();
vbox.getChildren().addAll(slider1, slider2, slider3, slider4, pi);
```

which will produce something like this:

[image]

**Note:** If you update the boundaries of the `Slider`s to from 0 to 0.25, the binding is even simple:

```
Slider slider1 = new Slider(0d, 0.25d, 0d);
Slider slider2 = new Slider(0d, 0.25d, 0d);
Slider slider3 = new Slider(0d, 0.25d, 0d);
Slider slider4 = new Slider(0d, 0.25d, 0d);

ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator();

pi.progressProperty().bind(slider1.valueProperty().add(slider2.valueProperty())
        .add(slider3.valueProperty()).add(slider4.valueProperty()));
```

Comment: One more question: How would I integrate it in the scene builder xml page vs  ...vbox.getChildren()addAll... ?

Comment: figured it out:

Comment: Figured out the solution: 
1. Update the boundaries in scene builder  
2. Then bind the progress bar and slider